# Setting different Bar title for ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewController with NavigationController and TabController embed in. (TabController is set as initialViewController)

I would like to change the tile of navigation bar, but if I change title of one viewController it is applied to all ViewControllers .

How can I write a code for each ViewController to have different barTitle?

[Navigation Controller as initialViewController]

[image]

[![TabBarController as initialViewController][2]][2]

Comment: you need to embed ervey root controllers in navigationcontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need to embed all your Tabbar's `ViewController` to `NavigationController`, So now every viewController having personal navigation and it is easy to set title to individual `viewController` and set `UITabbarController` as initial `ViewController` of `storyboard`.

So your Structure should be like

```
TabbarController
    |->NavigationController1->ViewConctroller1
    |->NavigationController2->ViewConctroller2
    |->NavigationController3->ViewConctroller3
    |->NavigationController4->ViewConctroller3
```

Check below image for more references: **TabbarController with 3 ViewControllers**

[image]

Comment: Set TabbarController as initialViewController. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @risa8 Yes set `TabbarController` as `initialViewController`, check the edited answer

Comment: I set TabbarController as initialViewController then made relationshipSegue to NavigationController. Now there is no tab bar appearing : /

Comment: @risa8 you need to add one navigation controller for each tab. Then each navigation controller has the `root view controller` set to be the different view controllers you want to display.

Comment: @risa8 You need to embed every ViewController of you UITabbar to `NavigationController` and then set that `NavigationController` as ViewController's of `UItabbarController`. Check the edited answer you get more idea,

Comment: @risa8 Welcome mate :)

Comment: ummmm now When I add shadow to top bar it appears only in the first ViewController.  Do you know why? :/

Comment: I am trying to set shadow effect to Navigation bar but it is only appearing in the first view controller. Before editing MainStoryboard it was working.

Comment: @risa8 Add the code in your question with detail where you are adding this code

Comment: @risa8 That great :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what Nirav is suggesting which is the correct way.

[image]

Add as many view controllers you want in tabBarController. Now embedd every view controller into a navigation controlller